# VB6 legacy system with modern web page

Tags: .net, vb6, applet, vb6-migration, xbap

I have a legacy VB6 app. I want to integrate it with my web app. VB6 app resides on client PC and I would prefer direct communication with my web page.

Options I was considering was Java applet or ActiveX or maybe xbap app (running inside an iframe of my page).

As u can see I am little lost in technologies. Would appreciate if someone can point me to right direction (or tutorial/example).

I am also not sure how this component will communicate with VB6 app (COM??)

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is here?  For example, do you simply want to pass data between your vb6 app and your web app or do you want to display pages from your web app within your vb6 app?

Comment: I just want to pass data from my web page to vb6 app (2-3 strings). and may be get some information from vb6 app back to web page.

Comment: You cannot easily pass data FROM a web app TO a vb6 app, but you can easily request data FROM your VB6 to your web app.  Basically, the VB6 app would initiate all the communication.  It can request data from the website as well as push data to the web site.  Going the other direction is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I pass data between VB6 and a website all the time.  I use the XML object which is easily accessible to VB6. The code I show below uses a classic asp page on the web server, but it could just as easily be any other type of page.

I have this function in my VB6 app

```
Public Function Download(ByVal AsmxUrl As String) As String

    Dim objDom As Object
    Dim objXmlHttp As Object
    Dim strRet As String

    On Error GoTo Err_PW

    ' Create objects to DOMDocument and XMLHTTP
    Set objDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    ' Load XML
    objDom.async = False

    ' Open the webservice
    objXmlHttp.Open "GET", AsmxUrl, False

    ' Create headings
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"

    ' Send XML command
    objXmlHttp.send objDom.xml

    ' Get all response text from webservice
    strRet = objXmlHttp.responseText

    ' Close object
    Set objXmlHttp = Nothing

    ' Return result
    Download = strRet

Exit Function
Err_PW:
    Download = "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Function
```

You can call it like this:

```
Dim Output As String

Output = Download("http://YourWebsite.com/data.asp?EyeColor=Blue&ShoeSize=9")
Call MsgBox(Output)
```

On the web server, you would have a page named data.asp that looks something like this:

```
<% 
Response.Expires = -1000 'Make sure the browser doesn't cache this page
%>
<!-- #include virtual="\include_database.asp" -->
<%
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"

    EyeColor = Request("EyeColor")
    ShoeSize = Request("ShoeSize")
    ' Do something interesting with the data

    Response.Write "Ouput here"
%>
```

Notice a couple of interesting things.  Response.Expires has a negative number.  This means the page expires immediately so you don't get cached results.  Also notice that the content type is set to "text/plain".  This means that the response will simply be text.

Answer (score 0):

It will help if there is a good separation between the vb6 GUI and business logic. You will need to refactor the Vb6 app so that as much of the application is split off from the Exe, and put into an ActiveX DLL, which has one or more classes you instantiate from your web app.

This would be easiest if you are using ASP or ASP.NET as your web technology. However, it may be possible to adapt it for other web technologies.

If you were desperate, you could adapt your Vb6 EXE for the CGI (Common Gateway Interface), but that is strictly old-school, is slow, and may not be supported on modern web servers.